# How to make Chrome spell check the whole text field?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

On Firefox, whenever a word is incorrect in a text field, it is underlined in red.

Chrome does the same but the difference is that it underlines in red only when I move the caret over the word. So if I want to spell check the whole text field, I have to move the caret from the beginning to the end of the text field.

Is it possible to make Chrome works more like Firefox and spell check the entire text field automatically?

Comment: When I type in the Chrome after pressing space button it shows the word with red underline and so on.

Comment: @avirk: If you paste a wall of text, you have to move the cursor through every word to trigger a spell check.

Comment: @Dennis, do you know any good extension for this? English language would be fine.

Comment: One that behaves like Firefox's spell checker, no. But [After the Deadline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fcdjadjbdihbaodagojiomdljhjhjfho) triggers a spell check by click or hot key, and it's much better that Chrome's built-in checker (language auto-detect, gramatical errors, etc.).

Comment: @Dennis, thanks it looks like After the Deadline does what I need. If you want you can post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides a custom Chromium build, it seems to be impossible to make Chrome's built-in spell checker behave like Firefox's.

There are, however, extensions that - while they don't function *exactly* like Firefox's spell checker, make checking pasted text easier and have more features that their built-in counterparts.

From [Chrome Web Store - After the Deadline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fcdjadjbdihbaodagojiomdljhjhjfho):

> #### Check spelling, style, and grammar in your browser
>
> After the Deadline uses artificial intelligence to check spelling, style, and grammar. Use it to check your tweets, find mistakes in your email, and socialize with confidence. Click the ABC icon in the lower-right corner of an editable area to proofread your writing. [...]
>
> After the Deadline checks English, French, German, Portuguese, and Spanish text.

Answer (score 2):

This was a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6424) and—eventually—fixed about a month ago (after several years).